# How to check for empty variable in PHP Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to check if `$video` variable is empty. I am using PHP based Opencart version 2x. My setup is:

**Controller:**

```
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
$data['video'] = $product_info['video'];
```

**View:**

```
<img src="<?php echo $video?>" />
```

I have tried using inbuilt function `empty` function :

```
if (empty($video)) {
  echo "Variable 'a' is empty.<br>";
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if model is implemented in controller. It should work like this

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product'); // this should be added somewhere before 
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
$data['video'] = $product_info['video'];
```

If you are checking `$video` in controller - the style will be:

```
if (empty($data['video']) {
  echo "Variable 'a' is empty.<br>";
}
```

For the view (.tpl file) it will be:

```
<?php if (empty($video)) { ?>
   Variable 'a' is empty.<br>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the slow reply.

After the checking ( Controller and Model all working ) , and i have followed the "view" code that you provided , it managed to work , which means that my view is wrong when "echo-ing" the result .